# Type “EventViewerComponent” is part of the declarations of 2 modules :Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm developing a dash board in `angular 7`. When I launch my app in browser, it works. but it returns this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type EventViewerComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: LayoutModule and EventViewerModule! Please consider moving EventViewerComponent to a higher module that imports LayoutModule and EventViewerModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes EventViewerComponent then import that NgModule in LayoutModule and EventViewerModule.

*`event-viewer.module.ts`*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChartsModule as Ng2Charts } from 'ng2-charts';

import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';

import { EventRoutingModule } from './event-viewer-routing.module';
import { EventViewerComponent } from './event-viewer.component';
import { PageHeaderModule } from '../../shared';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, Ng2Charts, EventRoutingModule, PageHeaderModule, DataTablesModule],
    declarations: [EventViewerComponent]
})
export class EventViewerModule {}
```

*`layout-routing.module.ts`*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
            { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
            { path: 'charts', loadChildren: './charts/charts.module#ChartsModule' },
            { path: 'tables', loadChildren: './tables/tables.module#TablesModule' },
            { path: 'forms', loadChildren: './form/form.module#FormModule' },
            { path: 'bs-element', loadChildren: './bs-element/bs-element.module#BsElementModule' },
            { path: 'grid', loadChildren: './grid/grid.module#GridModule' },
            { path: 'components', loadChildren: './bs-component/bs-component.module#BsComponentModule' },
            { path: 'blank-page', loadChildren: './blank-page/blank-page.module#BlankPageModule' },
            { path: 'event-viewer', loadChildren: './event-viewer/event-viewer.module#EventViewerModule' }
            // { path: 'event-viewer', loadChildren: './' }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule {}
```

*`event-viewer-routing.module.ts`*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { EventViewerComponent } from './event-viewer.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: EventViewerComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EventRoutingModule {}
```

It seems that imports and declarations are mixed up. but I'm not getting where should I add imports and declarations.

Comment: No, The error is saying that the "EventViewerComponent" is in the declarations of 2 modules. 
if a component is imported in any other modules but not put inside the declarations array. It is fine.

Comment: remove the component declaration from LayoutModule